# Error when check an empty element in array

Tags: java, arrays

why cannot I check if a place in array is empty ? 
I got this wrong message:

> The operator == is undefined for the argument type(s) int, null" 
>   on the marked line

```
private static int findNr(int[] trans)
{
    int emptyPlace=0;
    for (int i=0; i<trans.Length -1;i++)
    {
        --> if( trans[i] = null) <--
           return emptyPlace = trans[i];            
    }
    return emptyPlace;
}
```

Comment: Could you explain what do you mean for _empty place_ in an array of integers?

Comment: rolled back modification to tags, since this is definitively not C, either.

Comment: `c#`, `java` and `c` tags?

Comment: @Steve i have an array but its not full, i want to check which places in the array are empty and doesnt have any value.

Answer (score 6):

You can not compare primitive data type for `null`. `int` is primitive data type.

Comment: ok how to do it in another way? i want to check for an empty place

Comment: You have two ways. a) you know what values will be in array. Than you can use eg. INT_MAX to represent empty value and test for it b) you will have to create second array (bool) and store there flag, indicating if first array at index is empty or not

Answer (score 1):

You have to do

```
if( trans[i] == null)
```

instead of

```
if( trans[i] = null)
             ^-----------Mistake
```

Anyway in which language you have written the code?

Answer (score 0):

You try to assign null to the array element at position i

To check if the element is null you have to do:

```
if(trans[i] == null)
{
    ...
}
```

but this expression doesn't make any sense since an int can never be null (unless its a nullable int (int?)) so the condition will always be false

Answer (score 0):

Primitive cannot be checked with the **null**. So for particular primitive types use their default value to check.

i.e for `int` default value is `0` and for
           `double` default value is `0.0` etc.

So check as:

```
 if(intr[i]==0){
      //some logic
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

> if( trans[i] = null)

In the above line your are using assignment operator `=` in place of comparison operator `==`. If condition expects the final value after computation to be of the type `boolean`. Hence you get the error.
Also your `trans[i]` is an primitive `int` value which cannot be compared to a `null`. (Only objects can be `null` in java)

The assignment operator `=` will only work in case of boolean variables, something like this:

```
boolean flag = false;

if(flag=true) {
// this condition will be true
}
```

Answer (score 0):

First, you mispelled the `==` comparison. Should be:

```
if (trans[i] == null)
```

Second, the above doesn't works. Primitive values can never be `null`, when you declare any `int` variable, it's 0 by default.

Thats why:

```
int[] v = new int[3];

for (int i = 0; i < v.length; i++)
    System.out.println(v[i]);
```

Outputs this:

```
0
0
0
```

You should either work with `Integer` objects array or review your logic.

Answer (score 0):

1- You have forgot '='  ---> `if (trans[i] == null)`

2- You can't compare primitive value (int) with null